# 複合型プロパティの列名を制御したい

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
public class Hoge1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Hoge2 Hoge2 { get; set; }
}

[ComplexType]
public class Hoge2
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Hoge3 Hoge3A { get; set; }
    public Hoge3 Hoge3B { get; set; }
}

[ComplexType]
public class Hoge3
{
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
    public string Value3 { get; set; }
    ・・・
    public string Value99 { get; set; }
}
```

コードファーストでテーブルを作成すると以下のような列名で生成されます。

```
[Hoge2_Text]
[Hoge2_Hoge3A_Value1]
[Hoge2_Hoge3A_Value2]
[Hoge2_Hoge3A_Value3]
・・・
[Hoge2_Hoge3A_Value99]
[Hoge2_Hoge3B_Value1]
[Hoge2_Hoge3B_Value2]
[Hoge2_Hoge3B_Value3]
・・・
[Hoge2_Hoge3B_Value99]
```

これを

```
[Text]
[Hoge3A_Value1]
[Hoge3A_Value2]
[Hoge3A_Value3]
・・・
[Hoge3A_Value99]
[Hoge3B_Value1]
[Hoge3B_Value2]
[Hoge3B_Value3]
・・・
[Hoge3B_Value99]
```

のような列名にしたいです。

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Hoge1>().Property(entity => entity.Hoge2.Text).HasColumnName("Text");
    modelBuilder.Entity<Hoge1>().Property(entity => entity.Hoge2.Hoge3A.Value1).HasColumnName("Hoge3A_Value1");
    modelBuilder.Entity<Hoge1>().Property(entity => entity.Hoge2.Hoge3A.Value2).HasColumnName("Hoge3A_Value2");
    modelBuilder.Entity<Hoge1>().Property(entity => entity.Hoge2.Hoge3A.Value3).HasColumnName("Hoge3A_Value3");
    ・・・
    modelBuilder.Entity<Hoge1>().Property(entity => entity.Hoge2.Hoge3B.Value99).HasColumnName("Hoge3B_Value99");
```

と書けば実現できるところまでは理解できましたが、もっとシンプルに記述する方法はあるでしょうか？
（クラス階層の中間にある Hoge2 を列名のプレフィクスから除外したい）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Hoge1`に`Hoge3A`, `Hoge3B`を直接定義するのが簡潔だと思いますが、`OnModelCreating`での解決も一応可能です。
例えば下記は`DbModelBuilder`のジェネリックメンバーをリフレクションで実行しています。

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // Hoge1エンティティの構成を取得します。
    var etc = modelBuilder.Entity<Hoge1>();
    var etcType = etc.GetType();

    // Hoge1.Hoge2へのラムダ式
    Expression<Func<Hoge1, Hoge2>> hoge2Expression = e => e.Hoge2;

    // Hoge2のプロパティの繰り返し処理
    foreach (var cp in typeof(Hoge2).GetProperties())
    {
        // Hoge3型プロパティのみを対象とします。
        if (cp.PropertyType == typeof(Hoge3))
        {
            // Hoge3のプロパティの繰り返し処理
            foreach (var pp in typeof(Hoge3).GetProperties())
            {
                // Hoge3のプロパティを構成するためのメソッドを取得します。
                var propMethod = etcType.GetMethod(
                                    nameof(etc.Property),
                                    new[]
                                    {
                                        typeof(Expression<>).MakeGenericType(
                                            typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(
                                                typeof(Hoge1),
                                                pp.PropertyType))
                                    });

                // Hoge1からHoge3のプロパティを取得するラムダ式を作成します。
                var newBody = Expression.Property(Expression.Property(hoge2Expression.Body, cp), pp);
                var lambda = Expression.Lambda(newBody, hoge2Expression.Parameters);

                // プロパティの構成を取得します。
                var ppc = (PrimitivePropertyConfiguration)propMethod.Invoke(etc, new[] { lambda });

                // 列名を指定します。
                ppc.HasColumnName($"{cp.Name}_{pp.Name}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

しかし`DbModelBuilder`は情報の設定のみを意図しているため、エンティティ型で構成したモデルの情報が全く取得できません。これは`Convention`などの他のEntity Frameworkの変更ポイントでも同じです。ですので、上記のコードのように`System.Type`や`PropertyInfo`を参照して処理を行わないといけません。

ですので、`Hoge2`を排除できるような設計に変えた方が良いと思います。もし`Hoge2`がDBに関係のない場面で必要なのであれば、以下のようにインターフェイスを利用したり、

```
public class Hoge1 : IHoge2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Hoge3 Hoge3A { get; set; }
    public Hoge3 Hoge3B { get; set; }
}
```

マップされないプロパティをすることもできます。

```
public class Hoge1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Hoge3 Hoge3A { get; set; }
    public Hoge3 Hoge3B { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public Hoge2 Hoge2 => new Hoge2()
    {
        Text = Text,
        Hoge3A = Hoge3A,
        Hoge3B = Hoge3B,
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Column`属性でしょうか。

```
[ComplexType]
public class Hoge3
{
    [Column("Hoge3_Value1")]
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    [Column("Hoge3_Value2")]
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
    [Column("Hoge3_Value3")]
    public string Value3 { get; set; }
    ・・・
    [Column("Hoge3_Value99")]
    public string Value99 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: すいません、例が不適切でした。Hoge2 の中で Hoge3 が複数ある構造です。